# Matrices, vectores y cuadros!! C++

Tags: c++, c++11

soy nuevo en esto, estoy intentando resolver el siguiente problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por qué al ejecutar se repite el informe de facultad civil?
Quiero que al terminar de leer los datos del informe de facultad de sistemas, salga del for, pero no lo logro hacer.

Además, me aparece este warning:
[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

que lleva a esta línea

```
char* fac[3]= {"CIVIL ", "INDUSTRIAL ", "SISTEMAS "};
```

y a esta

```
char* materias[2]= {"Espanol ", "Matematicas "};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    

    int tesp, tmat;                                     
    int tcivil=0, tindustrial=0, tsistemas=0;           
    int ce, cm, ie, im, se, sm;                         //ce -> Civil-Español  ;  cm -> Civil-Matematicas, etc.
    int universidad[3][2];
    int f[3]={tcivil,tindustrial,tsistemas};
    int a[2]={tesp,tmat};
    char* fac[3]= {"CIVIL ", "INDUSTRIAL ", "SISTEMAS "};
    char* materias[2]= {"Espanol ", "Matematicas "};
    int esp[3];
    int mat[3];
    
        //For para imprimir la facultad
        for (int e=0; e<3; e++){
        for (int o=0; o<3; o++){
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
                cout<<"\n****INFORME DE FACULTAD****"<<endl;
                cout<<"           "<<fac[i]<<endl;
                
                for (int j=0; j<1; j++){
                    
                        cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j]<<endl;
                        cout<<" **** ";cin>>esp[e];
                        cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j+1]<<endl;
                        cout<<" **** ";cin>>mat[o];

                }
            }
            }
        }
        
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

.
.
EDIT: Rehice casi todo el codigo, pero ahora tengo otro problema
[image: IMPRESION DE LA MATRIZ CON FALLO]
He tanteado mucho, pero no logro dar con el problema, no sé por qué la suma de algunos está bien y la suma de otros no.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    //Declaración de variables
    string facultades[3]={"Civil     ","Industrial","Sistemas  "};
    string materias[2]={"Espanol","Matematicas"};
    int f[2]; int a[3]; int matriz[3][3];
    int auxfac=0, auxmat=0;
    string facmayor, matyor; 

    //Encabezado y lectura de la cantidad de estudiantes.
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout<<"\n          Informe de facultad"<<endl;
    cout<<"          "<<facultades[i]<<endl;
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        
    cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j]<<" ";       //Lectura del numero de estudiantes
    cin>>matriz[i][j]; 
        }
    }
    
     //Acumuladores para obtener a[3] = total por facultad
     //                          f[2] = total por materias
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            a[i] += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            f[j] += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    //Facultad con mayor matrícula
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if (auxfac<a[i]){
            facmayor=facultades[i];
        }
    }

    //Materias con mayor matricula
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        if (auxmat<f[i]){
            matyor=materias[i];
        }
    }
    
    
    // impresión del encabezado 
        cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"             espanol  matematicas  totales por "<<endl;
    cout<<"                          facultad"<<endl;
    
    //Impresión de la matriz y el total por facultad
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout<<facultades[i]<<" ";
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            cout<<"      "<<matriz[i][j]; //Matriz
            }
            cout<<"               "<<a[i]; //total por facultad
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
    //Impresión de los totales por materias.
    cout<<"\nTotales  "<<endl;
    cout<<"Por materias";
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){    
    cout<<"   "<<f[i];
    }       
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"\nLa facultad con mayor cantidad de matriculas es: "<<facmayor<<endl;
    cout<<"\nLas materias con mayor cantidad de matriculas es: "<<matyor<<endl;
    
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se que hay mucho que depurar, pero ahora me estoy intentando concentrar en imprimir y leer bien las primeras lineas del programa.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Empecemos, porque C no es lo mismo que C++ y no es lo mismo que C#.. si queres que te contesten en C++, utiliza solo esa etiqueta. Despues, ordena tu pregunta y tu problema.. despues de leer todo, no me queda claro tu problema... No se como seguir no es un problema...

Answer (score 0):

> Por qué al ejecutar se repite el informe de facultad civil?

Porque es lo que tu has programado:

```
    for (int e=0; e<3; e++){ // <<--- bucle1
    for (int o=0; o<3; o++){ // <<--- bucle2
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){ // <<--- bucle3
            cout<<"\n****INFORME DE FACULTAD****"<<endl;
            cout<<"           "<<fac[i]<<endl;
            
            for (int j=0; j<1; j++){
                
                    cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j]<<endl;
                    cout<<" **** ";cin>>esp[e];
                    cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j+1]<<endl;
                    cout<<" **** ";cin>>mat[o];

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Esos 3 bucles que te he marcado hacen que se pidan los datos un total de 3x3x3 = 27 veces. Si quieres pedir los datos una única vez, no encierres dicha lógica dentro de otros bucles. Cada bucle debe estar en una ubicación determinada para que solo se repita el código necesario en cada momento

```
int estudiantes[3][2];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    cout<<"\n****INFORME DE FACULTAD****"<<endl;
    cout<<"           "<<fac[i]<<endl;
    
    for (int j=0; j<1; j++){
        
            cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j]<<endl;
            cout<<" **** ";cin>>estudiantes[i][j];

    }
}
```

El código tendría algo más de sentido si usas constantes. También podrías usar `std::string` en vez de arrays de char:

```
int constexpr TOTAL_FACULTADES = 3;
int constexpr TOTAL_MATERIAS = 2;

std::string const facultades[TOTAL_FACULTADES] = {"CIVIL", "INDUSTRIAL", "SISTEMAS"};
std::string const materias[TOTAL_MATERIAS] = {"Espanol", "Matematicas"};

int estudiantes[TOTAL_FACULTADES][TOTAL_MATERIAS];

for (int i=0; i<TOTAL_FACULTADES; i++){
    cout<<"\n****INFORME DE FACULTAD****\n";
    cout<<"           "<<facultades[i]<<'\n';
    
    for (int j=0; j<TOTAL_MATERIAS; j++){
        cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de estudiantes de "<<materias[j]<<'\n';
        cout<<" **** ";cin>>estudiantes[i][j];

    }
}
```

Comment: Sí... Hoy despues de darle vueltas me di cuenta de que se repetía porque estaba dentro del bucle

Comment: El "Using namespace std;" me ahorraría poner el std:: antes de declarar las constantes?

Comment: edite el codigo, pero ahora tengo otro problema. Look up @eferion